# Android - How to prevent ColorFilter with Porterduff.Mode.Screen from blending alpha?

Tags: android, graphics, drawable, colormatrix, porter-duff

I've got a few images loaded up in my GridView, and I want to apply a reddish color to them using the screen mode of blending.

In my adapter I've got this code:

```
ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(...);
image.getDrawable().setColorFilter(channel.getSelectedColor(), Mode.SCREEN);
```

I also tried

```
image.setColorFilter(channel.getSelectedColor(), Mode.SCREEN);
```

But I always end up with something like this:
[image: Alpha channel is red]

If I use `Mode.Multiply`, it doesn't color the transparent background, but the result is way too dark. Is it possible to use `Mode.Screen` and not color the transparent parts?

Do I have to create a `ColorMatrix`? Could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Maybe if you remove the alpha component of the color: `setColorFilter(channel.getSelectedColor() & 0x00ffffff, Mode.SCREEN)`. Just guessing

Comment: No, that just seems to make the color completely transparent.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently, you can also use [LightingColorFilter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/LightingColorFilter.html):

```
static ColorFilter screen(int c) {
    return new LightingColorFilter(0xFFFFFFFF - c, c);
}
```

Then use it as a color filter for your drawable:

```
image.getDrawable().setColorFilter(screen(channel.getSelectedColor()));
```

This seems to work.

Comment: This works excellent! I have a bitmap with alpha, white and black colors. The result with this color filter is that the color is only drawn over the black.

Comment: i want to replace only the black pixels with white so i did `view.setColorFilter(screen(Color.WHITE));` and screen is `return new LightingColorFilter(Color.BLACK - c, c);` but it makes the whole image white

Comment: @ono you should ask a separate question

Answer (score -1):

Since standard Mode.SCREEN also changes alpha, you can always use your custom color matrix that only blends RGB and leaves alpha alone. Here is the sample code:

```
static ColorFilter screen(int c) {
    float r = Color.red(c) / 256f, g = Color.green(c) / 256f, b = Color.blue(c) / 256f;

    return new ColorMatrixColorFilter(new ColorMatrix(new float[]
            {
                    1 - r, 0, 0, 0, r, // r
                    0, 1 - g, 0, 0, g, // g
                    0, 0, 1 - b, 0, b, // b
                    0, 0, 0, 1, 0, // a
            }));
}
```

Then use it as a color filter for your drawable:

```
image.getDrawable().setColorFilter(screen(channel.getSelectedColor()));
```

Unfortunately, **this code doesn't work**. Looks like current versions of Android simply [ignore the rightmost column of the color matrix](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/android-developers/JZLcFqoe248/NOwlPM5RzW8J). Source code kinda proves this, too - [it only uses 4x4 part of the original matrix](http://androidxref.com/5.0.0_r2/xref/external/chromium_org/cc/output/gl_renderer.cc#1307).